# How to insert a different header for every line with sed?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I need to modify a text file with 770 lines, and add a different header for each of them, for example, I have this:

```
CWGAGATCGGAAGAGCGGTTCAGCAGGAATGCCGAG
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTAGGC
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGATT
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTACCGT
```

And I want to obtain this:

```
>seq1
CWGAGATCGGAAGAGCGGTTCAGCAGGAATGCCGAG
>seq2
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTAGGC
>seq3
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGATT
>seq4
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTACCGT
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you specifically asked for a sed solution (I wouldn't suggest actually doing it this way - but you could):

```
$ sed = file | sed '1~2 s/^/>seq/'
>seq1
CWGAGATCGGAAGAGCGGTTCAGCAGGAATGCCGAG
>seq2
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTAGGC
>seq3
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGATT
>seq4
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTACCGT
```

The first invocation `sed = file` inserts bare line numbers, then the second decorates themby prepending the `>seq` string.

---

OTOH if you know ahead of time that there are 770 lines, then you could do

```
printf ">seq%d\n" {1..770} | sed 'R file'
```

although this relies on the GNU sed `R` extension:

> R filename
>   Queue a line of filename to be read and inserted into the output
>   stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input line is
>   read. Note that if filename cannot be read, or if its end is reached,
>   no line is appended, without any error indication.

Of course if you don't know the number of lines ahead of time, you *could* do

```
printf ">seq%d\n" $(seq 1 "$(wc -l < file)") | sed 'R file'
```

but that would lose the advantage of only needing to read the file once.

---

In practice I'd probably use [@John1024's awk solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/947587/178692) or its perl equivalent

```
perl -lpe 'print ">seq" . $.' file
```

Comment: Nice clever use of sed.

Comment: Thanks steeldriver for your nice explanation, It also worked. I asked for sed because is the command that I know.

Answer (score 12):

Your task can be done with sed but sed lacks any native understanding of arithmetic which makes it the wrong tool.  Awk works well:

```
$ awk '{print ">seq" NR} 1' file
>seq1
CWGAGATCGGAAGAGCGGTTCAGCAGGAATGCCGAG
>seq2
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTAGGC
>seq3
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGATT
>seq4
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTACCGT
```

How it works:

- `print ">seq" NR`

  For each new line read, we first print the header that you want.

  `NR` is awk's line counter.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

Comment: I was going to suggest awk

Comment: @steeldriver The reason is that I was just looking at some c++ code <grin>.  Your suggestion is much better.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks John!, It worked really well. I was afraid to ask because I thought it was a very dummy question.

Comment: I agree that `awk` is a much more suitable tool for this. Another example that it is important to understand what the customer needs - not simply do what they ask (see the famous Ford quote "if I asked my customers what they wanted, they would say 'a faster horse'".)

Comment: For a less cryptic Awk script use `{ printf(">seq%d\n%s\n", NR, $0) }`.

Answer (score 5):

Using a simple loop:

```sh
count=1; while read -r line ; do printf '>seq%d\n%s\n' $((count++)) "$line"; done < file
```

The output:

```
>seq1
CWGAGATCGGAAGAGCGGTTCAGCAGGAATGCCGAG
>seq2
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTAGGC
>seq3
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGATT
>seq4
ACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCTACCGT
```

Comment: @John1024 Thanks, changed to `printf` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `paste`:

```
 paste -d '\n' <(seq -f '>seq%g' 1 4) file
```

- `seq -f '>seq%g' 1 4` writes newline-separated numbers to stdout
- <(...) is process substitution
- `paste` concatenates the corresponding line of each file, separated by a delimiter
- `-d '\n'` sets the concatenation delimiter to a newline instead of the default tab

Comment: can you explain the role of `1 4` in the `seq` command?

Comment: You can also use an anonymous pipe instead of a named FIFO (for slightly better performance or if your shell doesn't support process substitution): `seq -f '>seq%g' 1 4 | paste -d '\n' - file`